# Google Maps V3, how to get array of markers/overlays?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

Now obviously if I was just adding them in a normal fashion I would just keep them in an array along the way but in my case the markers are being loaded in, but I am using a KML layer.

So after the KML loads and the markers show up I basically just want to know how many there are, and I can figure out some dumb hack for this (loading the KML file again with jQuery and counting it there or something), but ideally I just want something like `myArray = map.getMarkers()` or `myArray = map.getOverlays()`, does anything like that exist?

It seems such a simple task, not why it is taking me so long to find the answer. Maybe it just isn't possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing, you have to keep an array and add the object IDs everytime you insert one.

Comment: The thing is I'm not inserting them at all, I'm loading them from an external KML file with 'kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({map: map, url: url});' which is an XML file with coordinates.

Comment: oh I see. Maybe you can provide us codes or a sample page on how you fetch your data

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're able to access the markers once you've added them in using a KLM layer. If you don't have that many markers, then I would say load them using the regular Marker class.

Maybe I didn't do it right, but last time I tried implementing markers using KLM layers I wasn't able to add any events to them, or access them at all.

If you only need to count them, then I would say load that same KML file using AJAX, and parse it as an XML and you can grab the elements from there to count them.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I was doing it in v2 I was just hoping with v3 the KML support would be better because it has the potential to be a quite elegant solution. Oh well.

Comment: From my experience KML is really convenient if you're adding a lot of markers, it really improves the drawing on the map. In my case I was trying it with 15,000+ markers, and it drew them on the map in a split second using KML, but it took a few seconds to render on Firefox, and slightly quicker on Chrome using the Marker class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the markers in a KmlLayer (it is rendered as map tiles by Google's servers). You could use a [FusionTableLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables) (you can import KML into the FusionTable, then modify the query to that FusionTable to filter the markers) or a third party KML parser like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) (which render the KML using native Google Maps v3 objects).

[example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=state_capitals.xml)

[example using FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html)